# Does UEFI prevent dual-booting/Ubuntu not to recognize Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot, uefi

Installed Windows 7 on a laptop with UEFI. Then went to install Ubuntu on another partition- Ubuntu cannot see the Windows 7. I have done this many times before and it works fine.

Would this be explained because I installed Windows 7 with UEFI enabled? Should I disabled UEFI and re-install Windows 7?

Comment: Are you using GPT or MBR partition scheme? Is Ubuntu booting through UEFI or through GRUB?

Comment: I used the Windows 7 disc to install windows 7. Then when booting from the Live CD Ubuntu cannot see Windows 7- grub hasnt even featured yet...

Comment: Dual booting on a default uefi system needs some additional steps. I haven't had to do this myself yet, but I would start trying [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI).

Answer (score 0):

When people say that the Ubuntu installer "cannot see Windows," they usually mean that there's no "install alongside" option in the installer. This seems to be a bug in the Ubuntu installer, but I've not studied the issue in detail. It's usually possible to proceed with the installation by using the ["something else"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-7-using-something-else) option in the installer.

Sometimes, though, partition table problems cause the Ubuntu installer to think that the disk is entirely empty. In this case, the best solution is to fix those problems. In your case, you've presumably got a GUID Partition Table (GPT) disk, and you've presented no partition table data, so I can't offer any specific fix-it advice. Instead, if you're seeing no partitions in an Ubuntu partitioning tool, I recommend using [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`)](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) and its `v` option to check the partition table's integrity. See [this page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html) for more on fixing GPT disks, and/or post back here with more details. (Edit your original question and post a comment to this answer.)